# Is it possible to build packages for multiple versions of Red hat Linux on a single server?

Tags: linux, build, package

I have a set of programs for analyzing radiation data and I want to build packages for `Red Hat Linux` versions `4.x` - `6.x`. Is it possible to build these packages on a single build server running a single version of Red Hat Linux or do I need to build the version 4.x package on a server running version 4.x and the version 5.x package on a server running version 5.x?

If I can build packages for several versions on a single server, must that server be running the newest version or the oldest version of the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to build `toolchain`  for different OS environments (toolchain for Redhat 4.x and 5.x) and with in toolchain you can build packages for specific OS. toolchain is like a `chroot` environments.
2. You can create multiple Virtual machine using `KVM` and build many version of packages using single node..
3. You can use `UML` (User Mode Linux) which is quite interesting... Check out following Link
   http://uml.devloop.org.uk/howto.html

Comment: Thanks for the `toolchain` suggestion, but I had already assumed that multiple build machines would be virtual.  Now for my next question. Is setting up and maintaining either a `chroot` or `toolchain` easier than setting up and maintaining a virtual build machine?

Comment: Virtual machine would be good and very easy to manage! About toolchain it required some short of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your packages in a chroot jail. You can use [mach](http://thomas.apestaart.org/projects/mach/) to do so.
Here's a [tutorial on building packages with mach](http://www.howtoforge.com/building-rpm-packages-in-a-chroot-environment-using-mach) you could refer to, though it may be outdated.